# How to display a required icon on the fly with Parsley.js?

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

In my form, I programmatically set some fields as required depending on some conditions. I use this code :

```
if (condition) $('#my_field']).attr('data-parsley-required', 'true');
```

And it works fine. But now I want to display a "required" icon such as red * when thoses fields turn required. I found some "parsley-sucess"/"parsley-error" classes that are automatically set, but no "parsley-required" nor "data-parsley-required" class seem to exist.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thank you
Loko

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your CSS:

```
[data-parsley-required]::before { content: "*"; color: red; }
```

If that doesn't do what you want, do it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marc-André for your answer.
I added a div before the required input but it didn't get that red asterisk. Anyway I managed to get it work with `data-parsley-class-handler=":parent"` and more precise css filters

```
[data-parsley-required="true"] {...}
[data-parsley-required="false"] {...}
```

To remove the asterisk when field turns not required.